# Class not appearing after requiring it in PHP

Tags: php, gcloud

I am trying to connect my Cloud MySQL in GCloud to my App in App Engine.

This is the code for the class which should connect to the database. The file is **connect_db.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\CloudSQL\MySQL;

use PDO;
use PDOException;
use RuntimeException;
use TypeError;

class DatabaseUnix
{
    public static function initUnixDatabaseConnection(): PDO
    {
            $username = getenv('XXXX'); // e.g. 'your_db_user'
            $password = getenv('XXXX'); // e.g. 'your_db_password'
            $dbName = getenv('XXXX'); // e.g. 'your_db_name'
            $instanceUnixSocket = getenv('XXXX'); // e.g. '/cloudsql/project:region:instance'

            // Connect using UNIX sockets
            $dsn = sprintf(
                'mysql:dbname=%s;unix_socket=%s',
                $dbName,
                $instanceUnixSocket
            );

            // Connect to the database.
            $conn = new PDO(
                $dsn,
                $username,
                $password
            );

    return $conn;
    }

}
?>
```

Here is my second file code, **all.php** ,  in the same directory:

```
<?php
use Google\Cloud\Samples\CloudSQL\MySQL;
require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/af/connect_db.php";

$db = new DatabaseUnix();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

$users = [];
$result = $db->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[] = $row;  
}

#a bunch of html
?>
```

I keep on getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DatabaseUnix' not found in /workspace/af/all.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /workspace/index.php(15): require() #1 {main} thrown in /workspace/af/all.php on line 6

#this is the line of code $db = new DatabaseUnix(); in all.php
```

Thank you!

Comment: Add `use Google\Cloud\Samples\CloudSQL\MySQL;` to the top of `all.php`

Comment: I adapted both suggestions, I still have the same issue. Apologies for the function, I had to adapt the code because I had too much code.

Comment: Are you using composer? How are your classes being autoloaded in? Are you using spl_autoload_register or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your `use` statement is incomplete:

```
use Google\Cloud\Samples\CloudSQL\MySQL;
```

You cannot alias a complete namespace, you need to specify the concrete class. In this case:

```
use Google\Cloud\Samples\CloudSQL\MySQL\DatabaseUnix;
```

Alternatively, you could also use the fully-qualified class name (but creating an alias with `use` is normally handier):

```
$db = new \Google\Cloud\Samples\CloudSQL\MySQL\DatabaseUnix();
```